# JavaScript: How to clear interval after specific duraion with condition executed

Tags: javascript, html, settimeout, setinterval

I need to run the below code and after 10 seconds the SetInteraval function to be stopped but in the same time to assure that the full word has been executed.

*The code I had written:*

```js
var word = "I love JS More than any Programming Language in the world!";
var counter = 0;

var autoTyping = setInterval(function() {
  var h3 = document.getElementById("myh3");
  h3.innerText = word.substring(0, counter);
  counter++;

  if (counter > word.length) {
    counter = 0;

  }

}, 100);


setTimeout(function() {
  clearInterval(autoTyping);
}, 5000);
```

So I need after 5 seconds this code stop and this happened but it can be stopped without ensuring that full word "Variable word" has been totally completed written on the DOM.

Comment: what do you mean by variable word ?

Comment: @SaoudElTelawy so you want this function run every second untill your sentence seen fully on the screen?

Comment: Exactly @ElmanHuseynov but I want to choose the time like after 10 seconds this function to be stopped but full sentence to appear as I had tried with no hope!

Comment: @SaoudElTelawy then maybe you need to set a time when each letter of the sentence will appear on the screen? For exampla if the word has 10 letters, make them 1 letter per second, will have results 10 seconds.

Comment: @ElmanHuseynov More clarification .. what you mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that you want to print the `word` variable to `h3` element, per letter, and stop it after 5s AND the variable was fully-typed.

Here's my solution with recursive approach:

[UPDATE]

- Added typing loop with timeout stopper

---

```js
// word to type
var _word = "I love JS More than any Programming Language in the world!"

// target element's id
var _target = 'myh3'

// time to fully-typed the word
var _time = 5000 // ms

// speed is depend on _time and _word's length
var _speed = _time/_word.length

// your auto-typing stopper 
var _timeout = 10000 // ms

// auto-typing function
function autoType (word, target, speed, timeout) {
  var element = document.getElementById(target)
  var counter = 0
  var stopped = false
  
  function typing(){
    if(counter < word.length){
      element.innerHTML += word[counter]
      counter++
      
      setTimeout(function(){
        // recursive call
        typing()
      }, speed)
    }else{
      // check if you want it to stop
      if(stopped === false){
        // ok. you don't want it to stop now. reset counter
        counter = 0
         
        // reset the element if you want it too
        element.innerHTML = ''
        
        // start it again
        typing()
      }else{
        // console.log('auto-typing is done')
      }
    }
  }
  
  // timeout is required. you dont want a infinite loop, right?
  if(timeout){
    typing()
    
    setTimeout(function(){
      stopped = true
    }, timeout)
  }
}

// execute it
autoType(_word, _target, _speed, _timeout)
```

```css
body {background: white}
```

```html
<h3 id="myh3"></h3>
```

Comment: @ Faris Han
Thanks for such an amazing explanation .. but what IF I need this word to be printed the first time and then counter being zero and printed again and again  ... Later on, after 10 seconds stop to be printed but unfortunately the word printed missing some letter .. How to overcome?

Comment: @SaoudElTelawy Okay, I see. Check out my edited answer. Is that what you mean?

Answer (score 0):

Well, you are almost there. In your `setInterval` callback add a line where you clear the interval whenever the word length is reached.

In the `setTimeout` callback first check if the `innerText` value of your element is equal to the word. This way you can see if the full sentence has been printed out and only stop if it is so. Otherwise the `setInterval` will just continue to run until the word length is reached.

```
var h3 = document.getElementById("myh3");
var word = "I love JS More than any Programming Language in the world!";
var counter = 0;

var autoTyping = setInterval(function() {
  h3.innerText = word.substring(0, counter);
  counter++;

  if (counter >= word.length) {
    clearInterval(autoTyping);
    counter = 0;
  }

}, 100);

setTimeout(function() {
  if (h3.innerText === word) {
    clearInterval(autoTyping);
  }
}, 5000);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer .. this is great but I need this function to keep running like full-sentence printed out then counter = zero and printed out again this done for 10 seconds and then being stopped by  (SettimeOut) but code to consider once to stop the whole sentence been written!!

Answer (score 0):

you can just have the clearinterval in your if statement, without the need to have setTimeout function:

```js
var word = "I love JS More than any Programming Language in the world!";
var counter = 0;
  var h3 = document.getElementById("myh3");
  
var autoTyping = setInterval(function() {
  h3.innerText = word.substring(0, counter);
  counter++;

  if (counter > word.length) {
    counter = 0;
    //clearInterval(autoTyping);
  }

}, 100);

setTimeout(function() {
  if(h3.innerHTML !== word) {
    h3.innerHTML = word;
  }
  clearInterval(autoTyping);
}, 10000);
```

```html
<div id="myh3">

</div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, guys but what I need @Ma'moun that this function keeps running for like the whole sentence to be printed out 3 times for example and after 10 seconds it is stopped but to consider the whole sentence be printed out.

Comment: not sure I got you comment, my example here run until the whole sentance is printed out, do you mean you want the whole process to be controlled so that it happens in for example 10 seconds?

Comment: Yes I need this to be like written and keeps repeated trying my code and then Mamoun to be stooped after 10 seconds but full sentence not completed then!

Comment: @SaoudElTelawy, I change the code to set the value of `h3.innerHTML` to be the value of `h3` on interval timeout, maybe that would help?

Answer (score 0):

I really like to use ES6 generator functions, when it comes to intervals. They make the code much cleaner.

Here's an example of a reusable `typewriter` function, that takes the element, the word and the interval; and returns a `stop` function:

```js
function typewriter(element, word, interval){
  let stopped = false
  const iterator = (function*() {
    //This try..finally is not necessary, but ensures that typewriter stops if an error occurs
    try{
      while(!stopped){
        for(let i=0; i<word.length; i++){
          element.innerText = word.substring(0, i);
          yield
        }
      }
    }finally{
      clearTimeout(autoTyping)
    }
  })()
  const autoTyping = setInterval(() => iterator.next(), interval);
  iterator.next()

  return function stop(){
    stopped = true
  }
}

const word = "I love JS More than any Programming Language in the world!";
const h3 = document.getElementById("myh3");

const stop1 = typewriter(h3, word, 100)

setTimeout(stop1, 10000)


const secondh3 = document.getElementById("my2ndh3");
const stop2 = typewriter(secondh3, word, 100)
//Even if stopped immediately, it types the full sentence
stop2()
```

```html
<h3 id="myh3"></h3>
<h3 id="my2ndh3"></h3>
```

To return results, you can even promisify this function, that has the advantage of having an exception channel for asynchronous errors:

```js
function typewriter(element, word, interval){
  let stopped = false
  const promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const iterator = (function*() {
      try{
        while(!stopped){
          for(let i=0; i<word.length; i++){
            element.innerText = word.substring(0, i);
            yield
          }
        }
        resolve()
      }catch(e){
        reject(e)
      }finally{
        clearTimeout(autoTyping)
      }
    })()
    const autoTyping = setInterval(() => iterator.next(), interval);
    iterator.next()
  })
  promise.stop = function stop(){
    stopped = true
  }
  
  return promise
}

const word = "I love JS More than any Programming Language in the world!";
const h3 = document.getElementById("myh3");

const promise1 = typewriter(h3, word, 100)
promise1.then(() => console.log('1st example done'))
setTimeout(promise1.stop, 10000)

typewriter(null, word, 100) //Cause error with null element
  .catch(e => console.error('2nd example failed:', e.stack))
```

```html
<h3 id="myh3"></h3>
```